# Loop not exiting in Java class

Tags: java, loops

When I run the script, the browser proceeds to perpetually open new tabs until I end the process in the task manager. Shouldn't this loop only open the browser once? Even if you ignore the while loop and only focus on the browser request I get the same behavior. Does this have to do with the try/catch? What's going wrong here?

```
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();       

Boolean doOnce = false;

while (doOnce == false) {
    try {
        d.browse(new URI("http://localhost"));
        doOnce = true;
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: why you want to execute a loop once? why loop then?

Comment: Because I thought my server was doing something funny, and by providing a flow-control structure I could stop whatever was going down.

Comment: You can try do-while loop if you have to execute the code atleast once.

Comment: Just a wild guess.... but the URI you call in d.browse doesn't refer to the servlet page itself, does it? Because that would kind of explain the behaviour as it would create some kind of infinite recursion.

Comment: I don't understand your construct. You create a new browser tab on your server machine if someone opens an URL on your server. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Yes that would be the case. I just realized that lol. Because I'm too lazy to copy-paste the url. It's for testing purposes. I may just use Selenium. The end-user will copy-paste URLs from a selection and the servlet will parse it and perform some function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute the try/catch block only once in `while` you should put the `doOnce`  in your finally block :

```
try 
{
    d.browse(...);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
doOnce = true;
}
```

but if you want to exit from `while` when an exception occurred you should put it in catch block :

```
try 
{
    d.browse(...);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
     doOnce = true;
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Would the fact that it's in my ``doGet(HttpServletRequest...`` method have anything to do with multiple executions?

Comment: I think the second one is suitable for your case

Comment: Okay I actually get what's going on now. Every time the new browser is opened it executes the command again.

Answer (score 2):

In case d.browse(....) throws an exception and doOnce=true will never executed.

Move doOnce=true into a finally block and it should work.

Comment: what would be the point of a "loop" that only ever gets executed once?

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
{
    d.browse(...);
    doOnce = true;
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If your call to `browse` above raises an exception, you will never set the exit flag.

Why are you doing this in a loop?  If your intent is to only do this step once, do it once as a statement rather than using a flow-control structure.

Comment: ``d.browse("...`` alone still opens the browser a million times. Could this have to do with Tomcat?